# Bokeh - subclass Figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Here's the trivial bokeh 'quickstart' example:

```
from bokeh.plotting  import Figure

output_file("lines.html")
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ys = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

p = Figure()
p.line(xs, ys, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

show(p)
```

This works.
Now if I subclass Figure, the script still runs without errors and generates the html page, but browser will only show a blank page:

```
from bokeh.plotting  import Figure

class TestFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    

output_file("lines.html")

xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ys = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

p = TestFigure()
p.line(xs, ys, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

show(p)
```

Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3):

Bokeh classes are highly instrumented in order to facilitate automatic serialization and synchronization between Python and JavaScript. In particular, every Bokeh class actually has *two* parts one in Python and the other in JavaScript. If you subclass on the Python side, you have to provide a corresponding JavaScript implementation. So, just subclassing on the Python side is not sufficient, you will need to [create an entire custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extension). Unless you are actually taking advantage of things that a custom extension can offer, then it is probably not worth the effort.

TLDR: Bokeh classes should generally not be subclassed, except to make custom (JavaScript) extensions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I'll look into custom extensions.